# Activity Indicator not displaying on view

Tags: swift, uiactivityindicatorview

I have created an activity indicator view on Main.storyboard in XCode to inform the user to wait while the asynchronous image download from Firebase Storage is happening.

This activity indicator should only show when they click the button to go to the next screen though, so I wrote the code below. Unfortunately, even though the startAnimating() line is run, nothing comes up on the screen.

```
@IBAction func participants(_ sender: Any) {
    actIndicator.startAnimating()

    dispatchGroup.notify(queue: .main) {
        print("it's happening")
        self.actIndicator.stopAnimating()
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "myParticipants", sender: nil)
    }

}
```

I would really appreciate any help.

Comment: Have you made sure the indicator is on top of all other views?

Comment: Start animating only causes the activity indicator to spin, nothing with regards to displaying. As an FYI

Comment: On the storyboard for the activity indicator, can you make sure 'hides when stopped' IS selected?